# How to display UIDatePicker to choose date

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/picker) documentation so that I can pick a date in my Xamarin.iOS app like in this image:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/picker-images/image9.png

But I can't get it to work. My code:

```
var datePickerView = new UIDatePicker();
datePickerView.MinimumDate = (NSDate)DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
datePickerView.MaximumDate = NSDate.Now;
datePickerView.Mode = UIDatePickerMode.Date;
datePickerView.Locale = NSLocale.FromLocaleIdentifier("en_US");
datePickerView.MoveAndResizeFrame(
    UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.X - UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width,
    UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height - 230,
    UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width,
    180
);
// Add(datePickerView); do I add it to my view?
```

I also tried making it my `InputView` of a `UITextField` but I get an ugly dialog that's not even usable like this.

```
var t = new UITextField();
t.InputView = datePickerView;
t.ResizeFrame(300, 50);
t.Placeholder = "enter date";
t.TextColor = UIColor.Black;
Add(t);
```

I am running this app on iPad with iOS 14.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related with the position(frame) you set on the datepicker,the view would locate beyond of the screen in that scenario .

Use the following code , it works fine on my side .

Click on the label , then display the datepicker menu.

```
var datePickerView = new UIDatePicker();
datePickerView.MinimumDate = (NSDate)DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
datePickerView.MaximumDate = NSDate.Now;
datePickerView.Mode = UIDatePickerMode.Date;
datePickerView.Locale = NSLocale.FromLocaleIdentifier("en_US");
datePickerView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, 180); //this line
Add(datePickerView);
```

[image]

[image]